# How to stop Album Art files from showing in a folder with songs?

Tags: nautilus, mp3

How can I stop showing me those selected file from songs folder?

[image: folder]

Comment: edit the title so it's more obvious what you're trying to figure out

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `find` utility  to delete album covers in our music folders:

```
find /music_path -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Now to remove the "desktop.ini" and "Thumbs.db" files use:

```
find /music_path -type f -name "desktop.ini" -exec rm -f {} \;
find /music_path -type f -name "Thumbs.db" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

***Tip:***

You could use the even shorter version:

```
find /music_path -type f -name "*.jpg" -delete

find /music_path -type f -name "desktop.ini" -delete
find /music_path -type f -name "Thumbs.db" -delete
```

---

If you want also to remove the images tagged in the audio mp3 files you can use the `eyeD3` application. Install it:

```
sudo apt-get install eyed3
```

Now you can remove those images:

```
eyeD3 --remove-images *.mp3
```

---

Take a look on `man eyeD3`

```
NAME
       eyeD3 - displays and manipulates id3-tags on mp3 files

       --remove-images
              Remove all image (APIC) frames from the tag.
```

---

Comment: lemme ask you a question - if i do that is there any effect will for windrows ?

Comment: `Thumbs.db` will be recreated as soon as you open the folder in Windows with thumbnails displaying. `desktop.ini` will also get recreated by Windows. However, the images of the album covers are gone. Unless your favorite music player automatically downloads them if they're missing, they should not come back.

Comment: @AlexAinik The comment above of ByteBOT is just perfect to answer you

Comment: @AlexAinik Also take into consideration that eyeD3 will remove the images that are in the mp3 files as tags. I don't think this was the problem to be solved here, as the screenshot does not show such previews.

Comment: @Bruni I added eyeD3 as general solution whatever the vase and insert specific solution for the above preview using the `find` utitlity. I edited my answer

Comment: @Maythux Thank you, I think it is much clearer so.

Comment: @Bruni Thank you also, your comment was the reason to improve it

Comment: i am still having the issue. its not solved. anybody want to help me by skype please .

Comment: @AlexAinik It works 100% maybe you miss something, what did you do? how did you tried it?

Comment: Hi, how do i uninstall eyed3 ?

Comment: sudo apt-get remove eyed3

Answer (score 2):

Use Nautilus [**Files** icon in the launcher]

Open the folder containing the thumbnails and click **Edit**, select **Preferences**, click **Previews** tab.

In the **Files** section **Show Thumbnails** click the drop down arrow and select **never** close the **Preferences** window.

Thumbnails should now be gone.

Comment: Indeed this wouldn't remove those Images which the OP is really asking for, your solution valid for enabling/disabling the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

open the terminal inside the folder that contains the music files & their Album art files & create a .hidden file using the command

```
touch .hidden
```

then type in the terminal

```
ls *.jpg > .hidden
```

this will write all the files names with extension *.jpg* in the folder to the *.hidden* file, which automatically hides the files which their names are in, in Nautilus.

You have to repeat the second command each time you add a new music file in that folder in order to hide it's album art files.

**Notes**:

- You **must** create the file using the `touch .hidden` command from the terminal. Copying another file & renaming it to .hidden won't work.
- This method will hide all .jpg files in that folder so make sure you don't have any .jpg file that you don't want to hide in there, or simply open the .hidden file and remove it's line if you need it there.
- This is a manual way so you have to repeat that second command each time you add another music file with album art in order to hide it's album art files. 
  You can create a script for automating the process , anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation of [eyeD3](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man1/eyeD3.1.html) you can delete images of `.mp3` file using the following commands

```
--remove-image=DESCRIPTION
          Remove image matching DESCRIPTION.

   --remove-all-images
          Remove all images from the tag
```

Just navigate to the directory where you have stored all the `.mp3` files, then typeenter code here

```
eyeD3 --remove-all-image *.mp3
```

Comment: Its an update as the command to remove image has been update (images => image)